# I'm curious about past tense continuous in this sentence

Tags: grammar

1. Last summer I traveled through China.
2. Last summer I was traveling through China.

What's the difference between 1 and 2, and why?

Please explain the nuance...

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference whatever in the objective events referred to.

The difference is **entirely** in whether the speaker is choosing to present the travelling as a completed act or a continuing one.

In some circumstances, this may have no further significance; but it may be setting the temporal focus for what follows (eg if the next sentence is a simple past, then 2 sets up an expectation that this occurred during the journey, whereas 1 does not. This expectation is not forced, and can be overridden by explicit time markers).

The difference could have a story-telling function: if a speaker uses 2, they may be inviting the hearer to mentally journey along with them, whereas 1 may invite distancing from the journey.

Comment: thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think the first sentence simply states the fact that your journey took place without indicating any intention to discus what happened during that trip.

> For example: "If you want to know whether I've ever been to China then
> yes, last summer, I traveled through China."

On the other hand, the second sentence sounds like you are going to talk about something that happened while you were traveling through China.

> For example: "Last summer, I was traveling through China when the
> whole Great Wall crumbled, because it was just too old."

Also, the second sentence could mean that you spent the whole last summer traveling through China.

> For example: "Last summer, I was traveling through China. It took me
> all summer to cross but hey, I'm a snail, so it was actually pretty
> fast."

Comment: thank you for your help. !